# inotifywait invalid option -d (daemon)

Tags: inotify

I'm trying to run inotifywait as daemon by this command:

```
root@server:/# inotifywait -mrd -e delete -e delete_self -e create -e moved_from -e moved_to /path -o /tmp/path.log
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
inotifywait: invalid option -- 'd'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Crosspost: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/191757/inotifywait-invalid-option-d-daemon

Comment: Don't cross-post with unix SE, it is evil! After your question was (unfairly) closed there, or you didn't get useful answers, is it ok to re-post. But only after that.

Comment: Your command works for me on CentOS 6.6. You neither specify the ionotifywait version nor OS version you are using. So it's not really possible to answer, could be an too old version.

Comment: @peterh what should I do now?

Comment: @faker how can I get OS & its version please?

Comment: @Martin Let it as is, it is not so serious thing.

Comment: @faker  `cat /proc/version`
`Linux version 3.8.0-31-generic (buildd@panlong) (gcc version 4.7.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.3-1ubuntu1) ) #46-Ubuntu SMP Tue Sep 10 20:03:44 UTC 2013`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because a) it's cross-posted to Unix/Linux, and b) the poster appears to not be conversant with reasonable business information technology management practices.

Comment: @JennyD Ok close it. But what do you mean by "not be conversant with reasonable business information technology management practices" ??

Comment: The comment "How can I get OS & its version" indicates a lack of prerequisite knowledge to manage a unix system according to those practices.

Comment: @JennyD sorry, I thought this is Q&A site

Comment: @Martin It is a QA site, but not all Qs are suitable for this particular site. You were right to post on Unix/Linux; it doesn't have the same audience as this one and your question would be on-topic there.

Answer (score 1):

There was a problem with `inotifywait` version. While v3.14 has `-d` and `-o` parameters, **older version 3.13 hasn't**.

This can solve that:

```
#!/bin/bash
inotifywait -qmr -e modify,delete,delete_self,create,moved_from,moved_to /path |
while read line; do
        echo $line >> /tmp/watch.log
done
```

And runs with `&` at the end of command.